# How to create a list with class attributes on the fly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

The code iterates properly, but is not able to fetch **vaf.features.name**

file.html.erb

```
<ul class="adc class">
  <%% _.each(features, function(vaf){ %>
    <li class="myclass" data-title=<%%= vaf.features.name %> ></li>
  <%%})%>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Answer !!! it was very simple.

i had to use only **vaf.name** instead of vaf.features.name

file.html.erb

```
<ul class="adc class">
  <%% _.each(features, function(vaf){ %>
    <li class="myclass" data-title="<%%=vaf.name%>"></li>
  <%%})%>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhh I don't know the `<%%` syntax in ERB. Aren't you also mixing ruby and javascript here? Anyway, I'd do it like this if the value is available in ruby:

```
<ul class="adc class">
  <% features.each do |vaf| %>
     <li class="myclass" data-title=<%= vaf.features.name %> ></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: the Value is not available in ruby.